# how to clean up allocated memory in C?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I wrote the following toy program and observed that the second variable **test2** will take the memory address released by the first variable **test1**. And even if I free(test1), test2 will retain test1's fields values. I wonder how to clean up the data left behind by free() in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct test_str
{
    char name[128];
    int Id;
} test_str;

typedef test_str* mytest;

int main()
{

    mytest test1 = malloc(sizeof(test_str));
    printf("test1 pointer address is %p \n", test1);
    strcpy(test1->name, "hello world");
    test1->Id = 10;

    free(test1);
//  test1->name = NULL;   /* this does not work */
//  test1->Id = 0;        /* without resetting Id = 0, test2->Id will show 10 */
    test1 = NULL;         

    mytest test2 = malloc(sizeof(test_str));
    printf("test2 pointer address is %p, name field is %s, Id = %d \n", test2, test2->name, test2->Id);

    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

> test1 pointer address is 0x2401010
>   test2 pointer address is 0x2401010, name field is hello world, Id = 10

Comment: If you really want to do this for some reason, just overwrite the data with zeroes before you `free()` it.

Comment: You can always use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/).

Comment: This doesn't really matter, since a correct program will assume the memory contents are unpredictable and never even try to read that storage before writing into it.

Comment: `free`ing memory means you give up all rights to it.  Memory isn't "destroyed".  You have free'd everything you malloc'd, so you're fine. Whatever's left behind doesn't need to be "cleaned".

Comment: do you have to set the struct fields to NULL (or whatever appropriate) before doing free() on it?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - Your comment was/is worthy of an answer.  By now though, I suppose its academic.

Comment: @Linuxios: `memset` is not good enough before `free`, because the compiler can and does optimise it away in that case (that actually cause security flaws in the wild). For the same reason just doing so manually does not work using non.volatile pointers.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is that sensitive, use platform calls to pin the memory and use a non-elidable call to some `memset`-variant to clear before free.

When you give memory back to the runtime, it is free to use it for the next fitting request. Whether and when it does so, or if it gives the memory back to a possible OS, is not mandated by the standard.

Aside: `void free(void*) {}` is a valid implementation of `free`.

Comment: is it fair to say _...is a valid (but useless) implementation of..._?

Comment: @ryyker It is fair to say it's a severly sub-par implementation for most programs. If that's what you want to say.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have mentioned, just use `memset` before `free`.

```
memset(test1, 0, sizeof(*test1));
free(test1);
```

Comment: @Deduplicator - Are you using a stamp?

Comment: @ryyker: No stamp, not even C&P. It's just that this comment was right for so many posts coming in just then.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Asked purely tongue in cheek.  You defended it well enough :)

Answer (score 2):

There is hardly any good reason on earth why one would want to do this...

Nevertheless, adding `test1->name[0]=0` before `free(test1)` should do the job.

If you want to remove "all trace" of the previous text, then you can even do:

```
for (int i=0; test1->name[i]!=0; i++)
    test1->name[i]=0;
```

Comment: @Deduplicator: What "is not guaranteed"?

Comment: The compiler is free to optimize the loop by removing it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Sorry, but I disagree. Why would the compiler remove a loop which sets each entry in an array of characters to 0?

Comment: Because it is not observable behavior according to the standard: You `free` it directly afterwards.

Comment: @Deduplicator: "observable behavior"? What's not "observable" about setting a non-zero value to zero?

Comment: `memset()` removes all doubt (if setting memory before free'ing it makes sense at all).

Comment: @ryyker: Is that supposed to answer the question above your comment?

Comment: 5.1.2.3 Program execution, §6. That part deals with what may be optimised away and how.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Again, this loop sets non-zero values to zero. Any optimization of the kind that you're suggesting would ultimately change the final outcome of the program, thus making it (the optimization) illegal.

Comment: @barakmanos - No, it was just a bad place to use emphasis :)  Simply suggesting memset (but don't tell Deduplicator)

Comment: @barakmanos: It does not change the observable behavior of the program as the standard defines it in the named section, which means it can be optimised away. This is the "as if"-rule.

Answer (score 1):

free() does not clear memory in sense of zeroing it – it just makes it available for reuse – and that is exactly what happened here. If your intent is to have alocated memory initialized, consider using calloc().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memset(test1, 0, sizeof(test_str))` just before freeing, this will simply fills the allocated memory area with 0.

malloc algorithm actually works by keeping meta data for each memory block it creates. So if you allocate / free / re-allocate the same size just after, you will probably use the exact same memory block, which explains why the new address is the same.

Comment: The compiler is free o optimize that call by removing it.

Comment: Only if the compiler can determine for sure that this removing has no side effects, so this is valid a lot of C instructions. Sorry, but the "is not guaranteed" because of some optimizations is irrelevant here

Comment: The `memset` has no observable behavior according to the standard, because you call `free` directly afterwards.

Comment: Please, the section 5.1.2.3 of the standard defines the behavior of a C program, and because your call is not observable behavior as the standard defines it, it explicitly can be optimised away.

Comment: @Deduplicator: As you say yourself, exactly what `free()` does is not mandated by the standard. Furthermore, you're at liberty to replace your C standard library with a different one than that which came with your compiler. That being so, your compiler doesn't know what `free()` is going to do with the data, so it had better not be optimizing out changes to objects which are then passed to that function.

Comment: @SanJacinto: No, and this is a security flaw which was met in the wild. Specifically for this reason, MS has `RtlSecureZeroMemory` for example.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: The compiler can and does inline anything it can get its hand on, as well as assume that mandated standard functions have the mandated behavior.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The fact that a mandated standard function has the mandated behavior doesn't mean it can't do anything else. A `free()` function which, for instance, logged the contents of memory before it was `free()`d would be perfectly compliant, and this kind of optimization would definitely have a visible side-effect on that.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: If your implementation allows you to give any standard function additional non-standard behavior, that is your implementations headache. But all parts must be in on the joke.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Nevertheless, given that practically all modern systems provide the C standard library as a shared library, and that library can be updated long after your program is compiled, the compiler is simply unable to deduce that there are no visible side effects, here, and hence cannot optimize it away. 5.1.2.3 says clearly that the compiler has to be able to deduce that a called function also does not cause such side-effects.

Comment: Well, you can run `gcc` in a mode which allows such. But that is quite uncommon. Normally, you just accept it optimising the heck out of your program. As the manual says, it is a freestanding implementation and the compiler of a hosted implementation, which assumes the library does nothing surprising.

Comment: Why would such behavior be "surprising"? Any memory debugging library that replaces `malloc()` and `free()` and friends may do all kinds of things in addition to just allocating and deallocating memory. Furthermore, 7.22.3.2 says explicitly that memory management functions "may, however, visibly modify the storage that they allocate or deallocate", which would appear to settle it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, C functions don't do anything other than what they're supposed to. `malloc` and `free` simply allocate and free memory - nothing more. This means that they don't null-out any fields.

When creating a struct, a general technique is to clean up any relevant fields. In fact, consider writing a function that encapsulates struct creation, like so:

```
mytest create_struct(char* name, int id) {
    mytest t = malloc(sizeof(test_str));
    size_t nlen = strlen(name);
    memcpy(t->name, name, nlen <= 127 ? nlen : 127);
    t->name[127] = '\0';

    t->Id = id;
    return t;
}
```

If you'd like, you can also consider defining a corresponding deletion function.

```
void del_struct(mytest t) {
    if (t) {
        memset(t->name, 0, 128);
        t->Id = 0;
        free(t);
    }
}
```